# Angularjs chaining .then to depend on each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred

I have a chain of events set in .then statements.  I wish I understood a way to use .when() in this case.  This function is called on a ngn-click.  The issue is that I have to click twice for it to go through.  The $rootScope.csa has data going into the function that is used in the .then( functions ).  I when in inspect in the chrome debugger the and step through everything works fine I believe it is because the debugger is slowing down the application and allowing it to keep up with its self.  Other wise when I go through with out the debugger it goes so fast that it takes two clicks for $rootScope.csa.section.data to be populated for the next function to work as expected.  The first two then statement functions are services that are wrapped in a promise and $timeout on there end and the $timeouts do not seem to be delaying the process.  I have looked over q.derer() many times but cannot wrap my head around how it would be implemented in this case.  Any help or information to get to the needs that I am looking for would ne appreciated.

```
audit.LockData('section', $scope.csa.ID, user.ID, $scope.csa.Revision)
    .then($rootScope.csa = audit.RecordsCheck($rootScope.csa))  //  gets data and pupulates it to the $rootscope.csa.section.data
    .then($rootScope.csa = audit.GetInstance($rootScope.csa), function(){ return $rootScope.csa})  //  gets ID(s) from $rootScope.csa.section.data.instances.ID(s) and populates them to the $rootScope.csa.section.instances
    .then(function() {if($rootScope.csa.section.data) $location.path('/Update')})
    .then(function() {if($rootScope.csa.section.data) $rootScope.$broadcast('root_updated')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You always need to pass a callback *function* to `then`, not some call result (even if it is a promise). I have not wrapped my head around what these functions do, but try

```
audit.LockData('section', $scope.csa.ID, user.ID, $scope.csa.Revision)
.then(function(lockResult) {
    return audit.RecordsCheck($rootScope.csa)) // gets data and pupulates it to the $rootscope.csa.section.data
})
.then(function(checkResult) {
    return audit.GetInstance($rootScope.csa) //  gets ID(s) from $rootScope.csa.section.data.instances.ID(s) and populates them to the $rootScope.csa.section.instances
})
.then(function(instance) {
    if ($rootScope.csa.section.data) {
        $location.path('/Update')
        $rootScope.$broadcast('root_updated')
    }
});
```